# conversion of string to integer in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix

i want to print the memory of process id's. But, i am getting error in if block as it is unable to check for the string as integer is expected.

```
printf "%-10s%-15s%-15s%s\n" "PID" "OWNER" "MEMORY" "COMMAND"


function sysmon_main(){
RAWIN=$(ps -o  pid,user,%mem,command ax |grep -v PID |awk '/[0-9]*/{print $1 ":" $2 ":" $4}')


for i in $RAWIN
do
     PID=$(echo $i | cut -d: -f1)
     OWNER=$(echo $i| cut -d: -f2)
     COMMAND=$(echo $i| cut -d: -f3)
     MEMORY=$(pmap $PID | tail -n 1| awk '/[0-9]K/{print $2}')

if [ "$MEMORY" -gt 0 ];then

     printf "%-10s%-15s%-15s%s\n" "$PID" "$OWNER" "$MEMORY" "$COMMAND"
fi
done
}

sysmon_main | sort -bnr -k3
```

I'm getting below error

```
./sysmon: line 17: [: 0K: integer expression expected
./sysmon: line 17: [: 126704K: integer expression expected
./sysmon: line 17: [: 14216K: integer expression expected
./sysmon: line 17: [: 48187132K: integer expression expected
```

Comment: You need to remove that K at the end of the string. Read up on parameter expansion in the bash manual for some ways to do that.

Comment: I'm still getting the error even though i remove the K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this script:

```sh
while read -r pid owner m cmd; do
   if [[ $pid =~ ^[0-9]+$ && $cmd != "ps -o"* ]]; then
      mem="$(pmap $pid | awk 'END {print $NF+0}')"
      ((mem > 0)) && printf "%-10s%-15s%-15s%s\n" "$pid" "$owner" "$mem" "$cmd"
   fi
done < <(ps -o  pid,user,%mem,command ax)
```

Comment: How to convert the above mem to represent in GB?

Comment: i'm getting error as below. I believe it is because it is unable to take the float value

./sysmon: line 34: ((: 0.12281: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".12281")

Comment: ok try: `pmap $pid | awk 'END {print int(($NF+0)/1024*1024)}' `